# Send and trap SIGTTIN SIGTTOU in foreground process?

Tags: terminal, tty, signals, trap, stty

From the description of signals ([reference](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)), it seems like SIGTTIN and SIGTTOU are sent to a process only if it is in background. Pressing `Ctrl-s` does stop printing in terminal, if such flow control is enabled. So the question is, is it possible to actually pass SIGTTIN/SIGTTOU signals to a process currently in foreground and trap it?

As an example, save the following code in a file, `chmod +x` and run it. Then press `Ctrl-s`/`Ctrl-q`. You would notice that `Ctrl-s` does stop and `Ctrl-q` does resume printing. But the file `./trap.log` file will be empty.

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
touch ./trap.log
trap 'echo TSTP >>./trap.log' TSTP
trap 'echo TTIN >>./trap.log' TTIN
trap 'echo TTOU >>./trap.log' TTOU
trap 'echo CONT >>./trap.log' CONT
for ((i=1;i>0;i=i+1)); do
    printf "print $i\n"
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send SIGTTIN or SIGTTOU with `kill`, like any other signal. You can trap them with `trap` (in sh), like any other (trappable) signal. But <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd> have nothing to do with signals. They're handled by the terminal, not by the application.

If you want your application to treat <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> as a “pause output” command, make sure the terminal does not capture these characters (`stty -ixoff` or the `tcsetattr` equivalent), and handle them like any other input.

Comment: "But ``Ctrl+s`` and ``Ctrl+Q`` have nothing to do with signals. They're handled by the terminal, not by the application." Is there a way to bind ``Ctrl+S`` and ``Ctrl+Q`` in ``zsh`` to do something like send a signal? That is why I originally added ``zsh`` tag. Afaik, keybindings are only supported for line editor, not when shell is in interactive mode.

Comment: @codepoet Zsh key bindings only have an effect on zsh. While an application is running in the foreground, zsh isn't receiving input.